# How to define guild in discord.py?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
async def find_channel(guild):
for c in guild.text_channels:
    if not c.permissions_for(guild.me).send_messages:
        continue
    return c

@bot.event
async def on_server_join(member):
channel = await find_channel(guild)
await channel.send('blah')
```

This is my code and when I start the bot and it joins to the channel, this error occurs:

```
line 48, in on_server_join
channel = await find_channel(guild)
NameError: name 'guild' is not defined
```

How can I define guild?

Answer (score 0):

`member.guild` in rewrite or `member.server` in async

[`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member) has a specific field which permits retrieving the guild.

Instead of `channel = await find_channel(guild)` just do `channel = await find_channel(member.guild)` assuming you're using rewrite version.